# Show/Hide multiple Divs with same class name (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched for same questions and found only jQuery solutions but I'd like to make it using JS only.

I have multiple `div`s with same class name and multiple `a` tags. I want the info show up when user press on `a` element associated with `div`.

Here's my function. I've created 2 loops: one for `a` elements and second is for `div`s.

```js
function toggle() {
   var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleText");
   var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("displayText");
    for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<ele.length; j++){
    btn[i].onclick = function(){
   if(ele[j].style.display == "none") {
        ele[j].style.display = "block";

     }
   else {
    ele[j].style.display = "block";

   }
  }}}}
```

```css
.displayText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:toggle();">Show1</a>
    <div class='displayText'>
      Text1
    </div>
    <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:toggle();">Show2</a>
    <div class='displayText'>
      Text2
    </div>
    <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:toggle();">Show3</a>
    <div class='displayText'>
      Text3
    </div>
    <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:toggle();">Show4</a>
    <div class='displayText'>
      Text4
    </div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The issue is the method `toggle();` which is called when you click the `a` tag through your href doesn't actually do anything. All it does is setup handlers `onclick` for all the divs that are invisible.

A better way to do this is instead of using `href`, use `onclick` on the `a` instead and make the `toggle` method actually show the correct `div` as well as binding to `onclick`

Comment: the problem is that my `divs` and `a` are created automatically, so that's why they have same class name and `href `. Your method doesn't work in this case or I don't understand it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

@cirix has brought to my attention that my original code breaks because of the use of `nextElementSibling` without the necessary precautions to terminate the sibling chain. As it was before the edit if the last div was clicked it `nextElementSibling` would report a null since the last element would never have a next sibling (that's what makes last ...last).

There are 2 changes:

1. Added an extra condition to ensure that the only `event.target`s dealt with are `<a>`nchors, thereby fixing the issue.
2. Removed `classList.add/remove` and replaced them with `classList.toggle()`, that's an improvement, not a fix.

---

Use event delegation by wrapping all of your elements in one element. Then register the click event on it. With a little more setup you'll be able to control as many links as you want with just one eventListener. Details commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the parent element
var main = document.getElementById('main');

/* Register main to the click event 
|| when clicked ANYWHERE within main 
|| toggle() is called
*/
main.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);

function toggle(e) {
  /* Determine if the current element in the
  || event chain is the anchor that was 
  || clicked.
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget && e.target.nodeName === "A") {
    /* tgt is the clicked link
    || txt is the div that follows tgt
    */
    var tgt = e.target;
    var txt = tgt.nextElementSibling;
    // Toggle classes .on and .off
    txt.classList.toggle('on');
    txt.classList.toggle('off');
  }

}
```

```css
.off {
  display: none;
}

.on {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id='main'>
  <a class='toggleText' href="#/">Show1</a>
  <div class='displayText off'>
    Text1
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="#/">Show2</a>
  <div class='displayText off'>
    Text2
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="#/">Show3</a>
  <div class='displayText off'>
    Text3
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="#/">Show4</a>
  <div class='displayText off'>
    Text4
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The script breaks and isn't working as expected, you missed to check if a sibling exists and if the user clicked a link with the class `toggleText`.

Comment: How did it break be specific

Comment: Open a text div and click on the div itself and open the last text div and click on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add an EventListener to the parent container and detect which link was clicked and show/hide its next sibling div:

```js
var linkClass = 'toggleText';
var textClass = 'displayText';
var visibilityClass = '-isVisible';
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container && container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if(target.classList.contains(linkClass)) {
    var sibling = target.nextElementSibling;
    if(sibling && sibling.classList.contains(textClass)) {
      sibling.classList.toggle(visibilityClass, !sibling.classList.contains(visibilityClass));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.displayText {
  display: none;
}

.displayText.-isVisible {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:void(0);">Show1</a>
  <div class='displayText'>
    Text1
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:void(0);">Show2</a>
  <div class='displayText'>
    Text2
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:void(0);">Show3</a>
  <div class='displayText'>
    Text3
  </div>
  <a class='toggleText' href="javascript:void(0);">Show4</a>
  <div class='displayText'>
    Text4
  </div>
</div>
```